# Effective batch size using tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy

Tags: tensorflow, keras

When using tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy the effective batch size is the configured batch size divided by the number of GPUs or is just the batch size that was configured in the code? For example, if I want an effective batch size = 1, I just use batch size = 1, without using tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy; if I use tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy with 8 GPUs should I set batch size = 8 or = 1? Thanks in advance!

Comment: For n gpu if it's set batch of size n, then it will split up across the available devices (n). So, yes, it is effective.

Comment: Thanks, @Innat. So whether or not I use the MirroredStrategy the batch that I define is the effective batch?

Comment: https://keras.io/guides/distributed_training/

Comment: @Innat that tutorial is confuse to me.

Comment: If you have multi-gpu and you want to do data-parallel distributed training, then you should use MirroredStrategy  and scale up the batch size (`local_batch_size * strategy.num_replicas_in_sync`). This local batch size is the amount of data that will be passed to each gpu. The `strategy.num_replicas_in_sync` will return the number of available gpus, so multiply by local batch size will give the the toal batch size (or global batch size). Now, if you have multi-gpu and you don't use MirroredStrategy API, you code will not run on multiple gpu but will run on single gpu.

Comment: The above blog post is by far the most concise document, take your time to read it carefully.